# Using a Rufus-Scheduler event to set more Rufus-Scheduler events

Tags: ruby, rufus-scheduler

I've got a script where I am trying to use Rufus-Scheduler to create daily schedules at 1am (based around sunrise and sunset). When I run the code it seems to only run the first scheduler event and won't run any events after it. My understanding is Rufus-Scheduler is supposed to spawn a new thread with each schedule but it looks like it is blocking. Do I need to spawn the schedules off on a new thread? Do I need to create a new scheduler instance for each schedule I'm going to create? I've added a test scheduler at the bottom of the code and it doesn't get created.

Here's the portion of code which relates to rufus-scheduler

```
def get_todays_show()
  this_year = Time.now.year
  check_sunset
  #the time format that comes back isn't reconginzed by rufus scheduler so recreate it with chronic
  sunrise = Chronic.parse("#{@local_sunrise.to_s[0,10]} #{@local_sunrise.to_s[11,8]}" )
  sunset = Chronic.parse("#{@local_sunset.to_s[0,10]} #{@local_sunset.to_s[11,8]}" )

  schedule_array = create_array_from_csv
  schedule_array.each do |sub_array|
    earlier = Chronic.parse("#{sub_array[0]} #{this_year} 12:00:01 am")
    later = Chronic.parse("#{sub_array[1]} #{this_year} 11:59:59")
    range = earlier..later

    if range.cover?(Time.now)
      @scheduler.at sunset do
        madrix_call(sub_array[2].strip)
      end
      @scheduler.at sunrise do
        madrix_call(@off_slot)
      end
    end
   end
end
#set up the scheduler
@scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new(:frequency => 30.0)

#run it once to handle today
get_todays_show

#the schedule to handle the future
@scheduler.cron '1 1 * * *' do
  get_todays_show
  p @scheduler.jobs
 end

 @scheduler.cron '* * * * *' do 
  p "test schedule - #{Time.now}"
  end

@scheduler.join
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to spawn the schedules off on a new thread?

No, rufus-scheduler does it for you.

> Do I need to create a new scheduler instance for each schedule I'm going to create?

No, not at all.

Have you tried without setting a frequency (using rufus-scheduler's default frequency)?

Although you are not hitting a rufus-scheduler issue, please read: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

You are not giving any detail about your environment, it's very hard to help you.

Try to iterate from small to big. Have a small schedule thinggy work and then proceed one step after the other.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I am running 1.9.3-p385 using RVM on a Mac. The final deployment for the script will be on an Windows 7 box. I'll try a reduction.

Comment: Removing the Frequency seems to have worked… I'll keep running some tests and see.

Comment: It appears removing the frequency fixed it.